# Laravel ajax pagination with original collection

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

I have a catalogue of products which can be filtered by a few different select, and checkbox elements. The filter actions are posted to a `SearchController` via ajax so as the user filters, the results are shown instantly. The search terms/variables are **not** appended to the URL.

I had an issue with pagination as the default Laravel pagination reloads the page, therefore, losing what the user had already filtered. I changed the pagination to work over ajax in an attempt to swiftly resolve the issue.

My issue is the ajax pagination re-runs the `SearchController` in order to get the collection to offset the results. The search criteria again is then reset as the filters aren't posted with the pagination ajax.

I want to just offset the original collection when called via my pagination ajax. Does this result set exist and be reused?

```
public function filter(Request $request, Stock $Stock)
{
    // Enable query log
    DB::enableQueryLog();

    $Stock = $Stock->newQuery();

    if($request->has('model')) {
        $the_model = $request->model;
        $request->request->add([$the_model => 1]);
    }

    if ($request->has('car') && $request->input('car') == 'true') {
        $Stock->orWhere('car', 1);
    }

    if ($request->has('bike') && $request->input('bike') == 'true') {
        $Stock->orWhere('bike', 1);
    }

    if ($request->has('productTypes_chosen')) {

        $Stock->whereIn('productType', $request->productTypes_chosen);
    }

    if ($request->has('manufacturers_chosen')) {
        $Stock->whereIn('manufacturer', $request->manufacturers_chosen);
    }

    $Stock->where('show_website', 1);

    $stockItems = $Stock->get();
    $stockItems = $Stock->paginate(15);

    if($request->ajax()) {
        $view = view('partials.filtered-results')->with(compact('stockItems'));
        $view = $view->render();
        return $view;
    }
}
```

Pagination AJAX

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.pagination a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        getStock(url);
        window.history.pushState("", "", url);
    });

    function getStock(url) {
        $.ajax({
            url : url
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('.machines').html(data);
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.machines').offset().top - 150
            }, 'slow');
        }).fail(function () {
            alert('Stocklist could not be loaded.');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the laravel version are you using?

Comment: @KayoBruno laravel 6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that to resolve your problem, you need to use this:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function filter(Request $request, Stock $Stock)
{
    // Your filters here

    $page = $request->has('page') ?? 1;
    $limit = $request->has('limit') ?? 15;

    Paginator::currentPageResolver(function () use ($page) {
       return $page;
    });

    $stockItems = $Stock->paginate($limit);
}
```